# where is the Request/Response format for soap - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, soap-api-v2

[Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) I can found the entire rest service and its request and response and url it would be helpful if I got the same for SOAP

Can anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy for SOAP. Though you can get the list of all WSDLs via

- http://mage2-base-url/soap/?wsdl_list=1

And load those WSDL URLs via [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/).

**Note:**
 By default, it won't display all the WSDL list (only the anonymous).
If you want to list all the available ones then you can tweak the code
`Magento\Framework\Webapi\Authorization::isAllowed()` to return true.

Comment: The above URL will not display all the API list it will show only the anonymous API

Comment: Please check my notes above.